# Rails: Changes to object won't stick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, save

I have a model called a `voip_phone` that has a an attribute `schedule` which is a string that keeps track of which people are using the phone at what time.  Here's an example of a `schedule`:

`"mon{}sun{}sat{}tue{13,08:45,15:15;}wed{13,09:00,17:30;}thu{}fri{}"`

Here is the model code that won't work:

```
def add_shift(days, person_id, time_from, time_to)  
    return false if shift_overlap?(days, time_from, time_to)  
    days.each do |d|  
        insert_point = self.schedule.index(d)+4  
        self.schedule.insert(  
            insert_point, [person_id.to_s, time_from, time_to].join(",") + ";")  
    end  
    save!  
end
```

No matter what I do, I can't get this method to work. Here's a readout from the console:

```
v = VoipPhone.find(5)  
=> blah, blah, blah  
v.add_shift(["thu", "fri"], 13, "08:45", "15:15")  
=> true
```

This seems to work, but the changes don't stick.  Calling `v.schedule` shows the new schedule, but calling `VoipPhone.find(5).schedule` still shows the old schedule.  Calling `v.save` returns true, but the changes still won't stick!

Any help that could be offered to a karmaless soul would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing a "dirty attributes" optimization that was introduced in Rails 2.3 AFAIR

See [this article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects)

in short, call "self.schedule_will_change!" before actually changing it.

If it will not work for you, then you can workaround with 'dup' like:

```
self.schedule = self.schedule.insert(....).dup
```

Comment: Thanks, zed!  self.schedule_will_change! did the trick perfectly!